# Subject verb agreement

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

I think below sentence has a subject/verb agreement. Here noun is singular but there are two adjectives.

> Public and private life ***is*** to be governed.

If the sentence has an error, please explain with suitable examples

Comment: It's a singular noun with two attributes, and it is the number of the noun which governs the number of the verb.

Comment: Does it mean like this "[Public life and private life] is to be governed"?

Comment: @StoneyB - I'm not sure I agree.  What makes you certain it's a singular noun?  *Life* can be uncountable, and if we're referring to "public life" and "private life", then it would be *are*.  Consider "Red and white wheat ___ grown at the farm."  If we're talking about "red wheat and white wheat" it's clearly *are*.

Comment: @stangdon Consider: "Public and private life is the topic for today, should they be considered separate for politicians", the first part of the sentence is considering two aspects of the same life, the second part treats them as separated. "Public and private lives are the topic for today" could have a different meaning since it would allow one person's public life and another person's private life which may not be linked.

Comment: Here, we have a singular noun modified by two adjectives.  The number of modifying adjectives does not change the number of the noun, so the verb accompanying this singular noun  should be "is".

Comment: @lalynacar. Do you have any reference to make your argument robust?

Comment: ARYF.- The latest textbook I used was (Longman) Advanced FOCUS ON GRAMMAR by Jay Maurer;(3rd Edition)  Unit 10. Top of page 168. The previous pages deal with the order of adjectives. There you have examples with the verb after a noun modified by more than one adjective. Since this agreement of subject and verb is taken for granted, the previous examples only give importance to the order adjectives have before a noun. You can display this textbook on Internet (PDF version) (not necessary to download it).

Answer (score -1):

> *Public and private* life is to be governed.

For the above sentence, the only context that fits is that *Public and private* are adjectives for **life**; therefore, the sentence is fine.